# Csv sort and removal python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that has the following data in it .

```
192.168.136.192,2848,100.100.100.212,6667,"other"
100.100.100.212,6667,192.168.136.192,2848,"other"
100.100.100.212,6667,192.168.136.192,2848,"CHAT IRC message"
192.168.61.74,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.118.168,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.118.168,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.110.111,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
```

so far i have been able to remove duplicates now i need to remove 
lines where the src =dest && dest =source && message == message 
also ones where src =src && dest = dest ||src =dest && dest =source && remove the ones with "other" if their = is marked with "infected"
**basically treating them as the same connection** 
this is what i have so far to remove duplicates

```
with open(r'alerts.csv','r') as in_file, open('alertsfix.csv','w') as     out_file:
seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
for line in in_file:
    if line in seen: continue # skip duplicate

    seen.add(line)
    out_file.write(line)
```

basically

```
src/prt/dest/prt/msg
1. a/a1/b/b1/c
2. 2a/2a1/2b/2b1/2c
```

Conditions:

```
if a==2b && a1==2b1 && b==2a && b1==2a1 c==2c
    delete one of them being they are equal
```

or

```
if a==2b && a1==2b1 && b==2a && b1==2a1  ( c==other ) &&( 2c=="infected" || 2c=='CNC") 
    delete one that has message "other"
```

I am very new to python and any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the conditions when 2 lines will be treated as equal/duplicate. Could you explain it a bit clearer? Because I got lost in the many conditions you have in your text.

Comment: 192.168.136.192,2848,100.100.100.212,6667,"other"
    100.100.100.212,6667,192.168.136.192,2848,"other"                                                are ==  one needs to be removed                                                                    192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"     are == and other needs to be removed                                                                                      69.192.30.179,80,192.168.61.74,1079,"other"
192.168.118.168,1079,69.192.30.179,80,"infection" are == and the 'other"  removed

Comment: That doesn't make it much easier to read. How about you implement just one thing first. If you have problems with that, provide a simple and clear example that doesn't have any superfluous information distracting you and others from the actual problem. Consider creating a [mcve], in other words.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define the conditions of equality. For example, the following code will consider lines as equal only if both conditions are met:

- both participating addresses (ip and post together) are the same; I use a `frozenset` to add both addresses, so the order does not matter.
- the message is the same.

You can use `frozenset` (a built-in unmodifyable set) to build the keys for each line to achive the lookup in the `seen` set:

```
with open('alerts.csv','r') as in_file, open('alertsfix.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set()
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port, msg = line.split(',')
            src = '{}:{}'.format(src_ip, src_port)
            dst = '{}:{}'.format(dst_ip, dst_port)
            key = frozenset([
                frozenset([src, dst]),
                msg,
            ])

            if key not in seen:
                seen.add(key)         # we add 'key' to the set
                out_file.write(line)  # we write 'line' to the new file
```

Does this help you to achieve your task?